# How to scrape Facebook posts from certain location?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

We have spent several days looking into FB Graph API and third party tools for scraping FB data but cant figure out if it is even possible to scrape what we are looking for and if it falls into  FB policies (really not looking forward to start a lawsuit with FB).

We need to obtain statistic of how often is specific question (read - problem that we will try to solve) posted on Facebook. We need to get all FB posts filtered by three criterium:

1. Location - country or city of user that posted the post
2. Time - Some reasonable period of time, for example a full month, week or day
3. Keyword - keyword that can be associated with questions that we are looking for

We would then takes this data set and manually go over it in order to distinguish whats relevant to us and what is not. Maybe use some language processing engine like wit.ai or api.ai to use data set to teach app to regonize which posts are relevant and which not. But thats on us, later.

So the question: Is it possible (technically and also from FB policies point of view) and what would be the steps to get FB posts filtered by three criterium stated above?

Comment: No, that is not possible using the publicly available APIs, and scraping is not allowed. (There is the Public Feed API - but that is only accessible to certain Facebook partners.)